# ManateeSerializer Missing Method

Tags: c#, manatee.trello

I am beginning the development , and I would like to play with manatee.trello .
I try to just follow : https://devhub.io/repos/gregsdennis-Manatee.Trello

but I got an issue :
System Missing Method exception !

[My Project dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BsNa.png)

in Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Manatee.Trello;
using Manatee.Trello.Rest;
using Manatee.Trello.ManateeJson;
using Manatee.Trello.WebApi;


ManateeSerializer serializer = new ManateeSerializer();
TrelloConfiguration.Serializer = serializer;
TrelloConfiguration.Deserializer = serializer;
TrelloConfiguration.JsonFactory = new ManateeFactory();
TrelloConfiguration.RestClientProvider = new WebApiClientProvider();
TrelloAuthorization.Default.AppKey = "MyAppKey";
TrelloAuthorization.Default.UserToken = "MyToken";

var board = new Board("1vanGPWi");
Debug.WriteLine(board);
```

[The error during debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvbeD.png)  (F5)

is it a bug ?

Comment: Please don't link to pictures. If the link breaks your question becomes useless..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the latest version of Manatee.Trello.  You don't need to do a lot of the setup stuff you have; it's for older versions.

I'm not sure what devhub.io is, but the project is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Trello), and the [documentation](https://gregsdennis.github.io/Manatee.Trello/usage/getting-started.html) is up to date.

Feel free to open an issue on the repo, or I have a Slack workspace you can join if you have any questions.

Comment: Dear Greg, thanks for your answer, I really appreciate, I will Investigate from GitHub